# why i can not use Swich react-router-dom

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Gnw.png)

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import LogIn from "./components/LogIn";
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp";
import { AuthProvider } from "./components/Auth";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={LogIn} />
          <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I try to follow this website
https://w3collective.com/react-authentication-firebase/

but can not work

Comment: It's because of version difference. https://www.w3schools.com/REACT/react_router.asp check this

Answer (score 1):

`Switch` is no longer valid in react-router-dom version 6 or later. Instead you can use `Routes`.
I modified your code follows

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom"; //--change

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>  //--change
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={LogIn} />
          <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
        </Routes>  //--change
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: And also there is no need to write exact. By default all path are exact in new version.